# How to fix a runtime error on Google Fonts?

Tags: flutter, google-fonts

I'm trying to build an app and I'm dependency-locked so I can't upgrade the version of google-fonts on Flutter I'm not sure if it is solely an error that got fixed in a later update. I'm also new and a beginner in app development so this would be really helpful.

Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-2.3.3/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:151:29: Error: Undefined name 'familyWithVariantString'.

I've tried to delete and then flutter pub get my pod file as well as flutter clean but nothing is working as I compile the app again and again. And the error shows up.

Comment: Could you add your pubspec to review the version numbers please ?